# Last static cell separator line appears after reloading table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I'm using code below to get rid of last static cell bottom separator line and it works perfectly for cases when I don't need to reload tableView. Once I reload my tableView separator line appears.

Only code in super VC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let footerFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 
    tableView.frame.size.width, height: 1.0)
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: footerFrame)
}
```

And after calling:

```
fileprivate func showDatePicker()
{
    datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
    showsDatePicker = true

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -20.0, left: 0.0, 
    bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
}
```

in my child's tableView(didSelectRowAt indexPath:_) I'm just changing the cell's  height with date picker in:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    guard showsDatePicker else {
       switch indexPath.row {
        case CellIndex.withDatePicker:
            return 0.0
        default:
            return 44.0 
        }
    }

    switch indexPath.row {
        case CellIndex.withDatePicker:
            return 217.0
        default:
            return 44.0 
        }
}
```

and after that I have separator line drawn! Maybe it's because of STATIC cells usage and the only way is to add blank views to each viewController in storyboard? Replacing `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()` to `viewDid/WillLayoutSubviews` causes empty screen effect. I don't want to add a blank view to all my controllers in the storyboards, maybe there is a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: Can you please share the code, what you did so far?

Comment: Yeap, sure, but not much to share

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    } in my super class for tableView with static cells, and it removes separator until I reload tableView

Comment: I suggest you share above code in your question(Edit your question) and also please share TableView delegate & data source methods.

Comment: I did my best, hope now it's better, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share a screen shot?

Comment: Not a big deal, but it's a commercial project, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before displaying your last cell.

```
if indexPath.row == Your_last_Cell {

  cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 0);

}
```

create footer with minimum height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{

// This will create a "invisible" footer
     return 0.01f; //CGFLOAT_MIN
}
```

OR

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
 viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{

UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to find more generic way, if there's one

Comment: See updated answer, if you are looking for more generic way you should simply hide `tableview` default separators `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none` and create your own custom separator.

Comment: The output is the same, it hides separator until I reload

Comment: Add last 2 delegate methods

Comment: the ugly solution was to set separator to .none and manually add a view to each cell instead, so your answer was the closest one I suppose

Answer (score 0):

My approach to attain this result is as follows,

In your viewDidLoad function,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Add this line
    yourTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Define the number of sections for the table view

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

And in your cellForRowAtIndexPath Function,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell: UITableViewCell?
switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourfirstcell")
        if indexPath.row == yourLastRowIndex {
        self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, self.bounds.size.width, 0, 0)
    }
    case 1:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yoursecondcell")
    default:
        break
    }
    return cell!
}
```

This approach will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using static cells and don't want to implement  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` at all, in case I do implement it what shall I return for other cells? Just `UITableViewCell()` won't do I suppose...

Comment: @DmitriyIvashin updated the answer as per your scenario.